# Weird Javascript Array.prototype.constructor.apply behaviour

Tags: javascript

I am having this wired behaviour with javascript array. My objective is the create a new array form another array. My approach is following;

```
Array.prototype.constructor.apply(Array, [1,2])
```

and it creates a new array with 2 element in them [1,2] that works fine but when i put something like this..

```
Array.prototype.constructor.apply(Array, [3])
```

that is to create a array with one element in it i.e [3]... it creates

```
[undefined,undefined,undefined]
```

that is it creates an array with 3 empty elements!! Any idea why? and how i can create a new array object this way??

Comment: Are you just trying to copy an array?

Comment: No i was trying to create a new array form an existing one...

Comment: and that is different from copying because...

Comment: :) not really different :) i guess you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Array.prototype.constructor.apply(Array, [1,2])
> ```

It should have been `Array.apply(null, [1, 2])` actually. `Array.prototype.constructor === Array`, and when you do `new Array(1, 2)` you're not applying it on the `Array` constructor function but on nothing.

> when i put something like `Array.prototype.constructor.apply(Array, [3])` it creates an array with 3 empty elements!! Any idea why?

That's how the [`Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is supposed to work. When it gets called with a single numerical argument, it will create a new empty array with that `.length` (and you're doing that: `new Array(3)`).

> My objective is the create a new array from another array.

Use the [`slice` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for that:

```
[1, 2].slice();
// or, complicated, but works with array-like objects:
Array.prototype.slice.call([1, 2]);
```

Comment: Not me. Actually, `Array.prototype.constructor.apply(Array, [3])` is more like `Array(3)` rather than `new Array(3)`, although they do the same thing.

Comment: Yup, they do the same thing, so I thought adding the convenient `new` would emphasize that.

Answer (score 9):

That's because the [`Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) with one argument, `n`, produces an array with `n` elements. With more arguments, it creates an array consisting of those arguments in order.

Actually your code is not calling `Array` as a constructor: `Array.prototype.constructor.apply(Array, [3])` is more like `Array(3)` than `new Array(3)`. However, `Array` behaves the same with and without `new`.

This all begs the question of why you're doing this in the first place when you could just use an array literal. If you're trying to copy an array, using its `slice` method is a simple way:

```
var a = [1, 2];
var copy = a.slice(0);
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I also get `[undefined,undefined,undefined]` from an `Array(3)` call.

Comment: see my answer, Array(3) gives you a new array with length=3

Comment: a.splice would remove all entries from a, which might not be the intended behaviour

Comment: @Ela: Indeed. However, I've never mentioned `splice()`.

Comment: @Ela: `slice()` doesn't affect the original array.

Comment: yep yep, my mistake, I mixed it up

Answer (score 2):

The first ctor parameter of Array is length of the array, if passed, `new Array(3)` would for example create and array with 3 elements, but all elements are undefined of cause.

Because you use `apply`, the 2nd parameter of apply is the arguments array you pass in to the method you apply it to.

That means, if your arguments array you apply contains only one element, the default constructor `new Array(<numofelemnts>)` will get excecuted.

Comment: I think `new` is a good idea too because it won't copy the prototype functions for every array.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `func.apply(obj, [1,2])` is the same as `obj.func(1,2)`.  And `new Array(3)` has the same result you gave above - `[undefined,undefined,undefined]`.  Blame it on the spec, but that's how it works.  You have to pass more than one argument in order to have them populate the array.

Comment: You forgot the thisArgument, which is the first parameter to `apply` :-/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use concat or slice on the original array.  You don't need to bother with prototypical calls, because that is reserved for creating a copy of the `arguments` list, in order to convert it to an array:

```
var new_array_copy = existing_array.slice(0)
```

The `arguments` functionality I am talking about:

```
function a_function_with_some_arguments(/* arguments */) {
    // Convert the special arguments list into an array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

    // Returns a reference to the new copy of the arguments list.
    return args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) has a good description on why this is happening, but here's the short of it:

The Array object has two constructors.

In your first version, you're providing 2 arguments, which the Array object understands as "Create an Array with the specified values."

In your second version, you're providing 1 argument, which the Array object understands as "Create an empty array with space to hold the number specified in the argument."

So if you want an array with one object, I'd recommend bypassing the `constructor.apply` syntax and use something a little more readable (i.e. `var array = [3];`)